# preg_match_all doesn't return anything

Tags: regex, preg-match-all

I hope you can help me with this. I'm completely puzzled about this problem. Somehow my preg_match_all doesn't return anything. It's supposed to return either an error or an integer, but it doesn't. Error_reporting is on and everything, I just can't think of anything wring with this.

```
echo $string = '234,2345,34534,223'.'<br>';
echo preg_match_all('/,[0-9][0-9]/', $string).'<br>';
```

You can see the $string but the second echo doesn't do anything. I guess you'll need more information on this, but I just don't have any idea where this problem lays.

Edit:
running PHP 4.3

Comment: You're initializing the target string as `$string` but using it as `$test`; typo?

Comment: Fixed that! Didn't do that typo in my code though ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`preg_match_all` returns the number matches found, or `FALSE`. You want to pass in a third parameter, a referenced array, and `print_r` that if you want to see the results.

```
echo $string = '234,2345,34534,223'.'<br>';
preg_match_all('/,[0-9][0-9]/', $string, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

(Also, you're using `$string` then `$test` but I assume that's just a typo in the question.)

Answer (score 0):

You need to provide 3rd parameter as capture array in `preg_match_all` and check its return value first. Use it like this:

```
if (preg_match_all('/,\d{2}/', $test, $match)) {
   print_r($match);
}
```

Comment: In the original code I was using $test instead of $string. I changed it to $string in my comment, but forgot to replace the second $test, my mistake.

Adding $matches did the trick. I didn't know that preg_match_all only returns a value when using the optional $matches parameter. It doesn't explicitly say so in the PHP manual...

Thanks for the quick help! :)

Comment: If this answer helped you solve your problem, please consider marking it as "accepted", so users facing a similar problem in the future will be able to see it easily.